# Best way for processing over 150 million rows MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, javascript

I wrote a function on nodejs to SELECT 150 million records, process the data and UPDATE those same 150 million records using

```
UPDATE 'table' SET value1='somevalue' WHERE idRo2 = 1;
```

Single Update for each row concatenate send one single query string allowing multipleStatements querys on the db connection.

I've being encountering multiple errors as

- Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
- JavaScript heap out of memory.
- RangeError: Invalid string length.
- Killed process.

I think i might not be using the right technologies or programing technique

*Edit:

The data process i need to do is to take the 'wholeApiResponse' column value, parse that string and then insert the parsed values into new added columns (askPrice, lastPrice, lowPrice, highPrice, volumePrice, platformTimestamp), this end up modifying the existing row by adding new values from an existing string.
[image]

Comment: Are you pulling all 150 million rows back from the server before processing them?

Comment: Add a LIMIT and recursively UPDATE until all rows are updated?

Comment: @J.D. Yes, first SELECT * FROM 'table' (these are the 150 million) then PROCESS each row and return the UPDATE query

Comment: @jerichorivera I tried breaking the 150 million rows in chunks of 15 million, but still with 15 mill it takes around 8 hours and the process end up being killed

Comment: Break it by 10k rows increase max-allowed-packet to 1G on both server and client

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing? Is it data or relational logic?...if so, you're likely best off doing it in MySQL instead of Node.js. 150 million rows is a lot to move across servers to then process. If you can provide an example of the before and after data, that would be helpful. Also how *wide* is a row in that table? E.g. how many columns and what types for a rough calculation.

Comment: @J.D. im doing data processing, i just edit my question explaining the process.

Comment: @ChristopherMartinez Gotcha, thanks for the example, I understand your goal, and it looks like you're dealing with financial data. I have experience working with *big data* in the Financial Tech industry. In that case, your best bet is to parse it as it's coming into your MySQL database. Basically proactively parse / perform your **ETL** on the data and then store it in MySQL already in a **normalized** form. Alternatively you can look into data processing systems like **ElasticSearch** which is designed specifically for the purpose of parsing meaningful data points from large blocks of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big Updates (and Deletes) are problematic.

Plan A:  Avoid the big update.  If value1 should always be 'somevalue' when idRo2 = 1, then don't store it in the table; store it elsewhere and use a `JOIN`.  Then, instead of checking 150M rows, you are changing exactly 1 row.

Plan B:  Do the Update in chunks of 1K rows at a time.  This avoids timeouts, and a number of other *potential* problems.  Details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks .  Even 10K can be problematic, hence my recommendation of 1K.  Anyway, going beyond 1K is getting into "diminishing returns".

Plan C:  Tells us what `value1` and `idRo2` are really called.  That might lead to some specific suggestions.

Minor issues with datatypes.  Shrinking the table size will help performance some.

- `INT SIGNED` has a limit of 2 billion.  150M is getting kinda close to it.  Keep your eye on any `AUTO_INCREMENTs`.
- Similarly, `INT` for `idCurrencyPair` may be wasting space.  (`INT` takes 4 bytes; there are smaller datatypes)
- `DOUBLE` can lead to rounding errors.  And it take 8 bytes.  Consider `DECIMAL(...)`.
- `platformTimestamp DOUBLE` -- Huh?
- I'll bet that `LONGTEXT` is rarely used?  We should discuss better ways to store it.